# push checked checkbox value with multiple ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-options

I have days option for user.

My expected output will be, when a user click submit

- if monday and tuesday is selected it should be `[1,2]`
- if weekdays is selected it should be string `'weekdays'`

I have too many restriction here because the api is heavily nested so I prefer to hardcode the days value. But I don't know how to proceed further. The only way I can think of is assign ng-model to every input and do push, but I feel that's not proper.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NfTgmsuZlGh6QUVZj8HG?p=preview

Need help.

Comment: can you use a ng-switch?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way also
In Controller

```
  $scope.items = [{"day":"monday","show":"1"},{"day":"tuesday","show":"2"},{"day":"weekdays","show":"weekdays"}];
```

in html

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item.show as item.day for item in items">
     <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

output: {{selection}}

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<div class="days-group" ng-repeat="timeType in timeTypes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Weekdays" value="weekdays" ng-model="timeType.isSelected" ng-checked="timeType.isSelected">
    <label for="Weekdays">{{timeType.type}}</label>
</div>
```

And `controller`:

```
$scope.timeTypes = [
                    { id: 1, type: "weekends", isSelected: false }, 
                    { id: 2, type: "weekdays", isSelected: false }
                   ];
```

Same for days also.

Check working `jsfiddle` link:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/oho7qxv1/
```

Check `console` for required format.

Cheers.